# What screams from the ears and listens from the mouth?

Tags: riddle

I have ears but failed to listen

I have mouth but failed to scream

but good thing!

I have ears to scream

I have mouth to listen

Comment: Makes me think of creating a Mr. Potato head :p

Comment: very creative riddle :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Are you:

> A phone

I have ears but failed to listen
I have mouth but failed to scream

> Phones have ear and mouth pieces

I have ears to scream
I have mouth to listen

> but the ear piece produces noise (screams) and the mouth piece listens

Answer (score 11):

Are you a

> [image]

I have ears but failed to listen
I have mouth but failed to scream

> The presumably ears don't listen nor the mouth piece speaks or screams

I have ears to scream
I have mouth to listen

> Put on a sthetho and speak on it. You will know what a [image] is :-)

Comment: I did that before.. feels like i'm on a recording studio :D

Answer (score 3):

Screams from the ears
Listen from the mouth seems to describe

> headset?

Comment: +1 when it comes to physical appearance, headset is the closer. it has also a mic for mouth and speakers for ears :). the problem on *headset* is that it needs to be connected to a device which wasn't mentioned on the riddle

Comment: @DyrandzFamador, but it doesn't say that it isn't connected to anything either ;)

Comment: actually, i thought of a headset before.. but the main idea here is "listening and speaking".. so for me, phone is the answer, because the phone's purpose is for call and also has already an earpiece and mouthpiece which being used for calling.. headset is just an external earpiece and mouthpiece that needs to be connected to a phone or any gadgets. (but i'm not 100% sure :D )

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like

> a cave... specifically The Ear of Dionysius
>  [image: Ear of Dionysius]

The mouth listens:

> A cave has a mouth, which in this case is used to evesdrop
>  from wikipedia: *"Dionysius used the cave as a prison for political dissidents, and by means of the perfect acoustics eavesdropped on the plans and secrets of his captives"*

The ear screams:

> The ear itself is the cave, which amplifies the sounds (thus, the ear screams)
>  from wikipedia: *"Another more gruesome legend claims that Dionysius carved the cave in its shape so that it would amplify the screams of prisoners being tortured in it."*

source:

> image and all quotes:
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_of_Dionysius